# Graph visualization and editing

Tags: data-visualization, graphs

I'm looking for software that will allow me to:

1. Import an adjacency matrix (ideally one with weights, rather than just binary) and visualize the graph
2. Manually edit the labels and positions of the nodes by clicking & dragging

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) can do the editing. I'm not sure about importing an adjacency matrix. Gephi is Java-based and  offers an interactive editor, IDE-style, if this is what you want. But interactive editing is feasible only for very small graphs.

I personally would use R and the [ggraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggraph/) package (which is a wrapper for the [igraph](https://igraph.org/) C library/toolset) for this, and do it programmatically.

The free [visjs](http://visjs.org) library also has a network module, see this [example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/manipulationEditEdgeNoDrag.html) and allows to edit a network/small graph inside your browser window.